# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-y|}} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I am asked to evaluate de following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-y|}} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$

---

**My attempt.**

Note that
$$
    \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} = 1, \text{ if } x-y > 0
    \qquad\qquad
    \text{ and }
    \qquad\qquad
    \frac{y-x}{|x-y|} = 1, \text{ if } x-y < 0
$$

Thus,
\begin{align*}
    &\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-y|}} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y
    %
    = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-y|}} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \\[5pt]
    %
    &\implies \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-y}} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} \mathrm{d}x
    %
    = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \mathrm{d}u
    %
    = 2u^{\frac{1}{2}} + k \qquad\qquad \left( u = |x-y|, \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} \mathrm{d}x\right)\\[5pt]
    %
    &\implies \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-y|}} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} \mathrm{d}x
    %
    = 2 \sqrt{|x-y|} \Big|_{0}^{1}
    %
    = 2 \sqrt{|1-y|} - 2 \sqrt{|-y|}
    %
    = 2 \left( \sqrt{1-y} - \sqrt{y} \right)\\[5pt]
    %
    &\implies 2\int_{0}^{1} \left[ \sqrt{1-y} - \sqrt{y} \right] \mathrm{d}y
    %
    = -\tfrac{4}{3} \left[ (1-y)^{3/2}
        + y^{3/2} \right] \Big|_{0}^{1}
    %
    = 0
\end{align*}

According to WolframAlpha this answer is incorrect and the actual value should be $\frac{8}{3}$.

Moreover, [throwing the indefinite integral with respect to x](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5BAbs%5Bx-y%5D%5D%5D%2Cx%5D) to Wolfram yields $\sqrt{y-x}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)-1) + \sqrt{x-y}(\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)+1)$. For this last result I have no clue on how to get there...

Also, integration in the given bounds should not be a problem since removing the line y=x (where the function is not determined) is a set of length 0.

Comment: But common sense does tell you that the integral has to be positive (if it converges), right? It is double the value of $\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac1{\sqrt{x-y}}\,dy\,dx$. An easy approach is to make a change of variables, if you've learned to do such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very first step contains an error, since multiplication by $(x-y)/|x-y|$ on the unit square will cause the sign of the integrand to be reversed for the region $x < y$.  This is why you get $0$.

Instead, recognize the symmetry of the integrand about $x = y$ and compute the half integral $$\int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-y|}} \, dx \, dy = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=y}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-y}} \, dx \, dy = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{u=0}^{1-y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \, du \, dy.$$

Comment: I had not taken into account the orden of integration when multiplying by $(x-y)/|x-y|$. Thank you so much,